# Microsoft Store can't connect to internet

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, windows-store

I have encountered a simple yet strange problem: I can't open Microsoft Store webpages using Microsoft Store.

I am in China, behind the infamous Great Firewall of China, I use a multitude of ***FREE*** proxies to bypass it, I am currently using Lantern, its HTTP Proxy port is 1053 (127.0.0.1:1053), it auto-connects to servers in South Korea, my OS's region is set to Mainland China, displayed language is English(United States).

Now, while Lantern is on, I get this:

[image]

While Lantern is off:

[image]

Funny, in Settings, it always shows this:

[image]

While Lantern is running, I have no trouble openning Google, Youtube, Quora, Facebook... whatsoever, I can access any website(provided they are online), I have no trouble ping, tracert... And Lantern also proxies PowerShell traffic.

While it is off, well, you know what that means, but I can still ping, tracert...

The point is that I have properly set up my network connection, but Microsoft Store somehow can't use it...

Don't suggest DISM and SFC and the like, haven't tried it yet ***TODAY***, but a few days ago I have run:

```
dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup
dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:D:\sources\install.wim
sfc /scannow
```

And they said "no component store corruption detected","the restore operation completed succesfully","windows resource protection did not find any integrity violations"...

And they ***DID NOT*** fix the problem. And there is no way my system is corrupted.

And I just did a repair install umpteen days ago, I first encountered this problem when I open the Store immediately after reinstallation...

And these are what I have tried(and ***FAILED***) to fix this issue:

```
devcon disable *dev_8168*
devcon enable *dev_8168*
choice /t 3 /n /d y >nul
netsh winsock reset
netsh winhttp reset proxy
netsh http flush log buffer
net start dot3svc
netsh lan reconnect
net stop dot3svc
choice /t 3 /n /d y >nul
netsh int ip reset
netsh int ipv4 reset
netsh int ipv6 reset
netsh int httpstunnel reset
netsh int portproxy reset
netsh int tcp reset
choice /t 3 /n /d y >nul
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /all
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
ipconfig /renew
taskkill /f /fi "services eq wuauserv"
net stop cryptsvc
net stop bits
net stop msiserver
ren c:\windows\softwaredistribution softwaredistribution.old
rd c:\windows\softwaredistribution\datastore /s /q
rd c:\windows\softwaredistribution\download /s /q
ren %systemroot%\system32\catroot2 catroot2.bak
net start bits
net start wuauserv
net start appidsvc
net start cryptsvc
wsreset
```

And I really am at my wits' end, I don't want to do a clean reinstall, because sure it will fix this problem for once, but then I am pretty sure it will magically recur, can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Do you have User Account Control (UAC) Turned on (enabled)?

Comment: That annoying thing that pops up whenever I try to run a program? I had turned it off, I had set it to never notify...

Comment: Do I have to turn it on?

Comment: To me, it is like a very overprotective parent, protecting me from myself... I always know what I am doing, and UAC is frustrating, it seems I will stay away from Universal Windows Platform then, it is aimed at tablets, I use desktop...

Comment: Tablet users do need protection of UAC...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Store apps won't work properly if you are using a proxy server,
so you must add them to the proxy bypass list:

- Run `inetcpl.cpl` (Internet Properties)
- Click the Connections tab
- Click LAN Settings
- Click Advanced
- In the Proxy Settings window, Exceptions section, input the following entries,
  separated by comma:

  `login.live.com, account.live.com, clientconfig.passport.net, wustat.windows.com, *.windowsupdate.com, *.wns.windows.com, *.hotmail.com, *.outlook.com, *.microsoft.com, *.msftncsi.com`

---

An alternative is to use `regedit` to position to the registry key
`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`
and set the `ProxyOverride` item to:

`login.live.com; account.live.com; clientconfig.passport.net; wustat.windows.com; *.windowsupdate.com; *.wns.windows.com; *.hotmail.com; *.outlook.com; *.microsoft.com; *.msftncsi.com`

References:

- [Use Authenticated Proxy Servers to fix Windows Store Apps Installation errors](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/authenticated-proxy-servers-windows-store-apps-update)
- [Configure client proxy server settings by using a registry file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/configure-client-proxy-server-settings-by-registry-file)

Comment: Thank you, that should do it, it is so simple but it is also really well hidden, no wonder I couldn't find it...

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I had just solved this problem, User Account Control is still off, it seems I have to completely reset network after closing Lantern to gain access to local Microsoft Store...

To do this, just close Lantern, reset network and ***Restart computer***(I have downloaded devcon.exe and put it to System32):

```
taskkill /f /im "lantern.exe"
devcon disable *dev_8168*
devcon enable *dev_8168*
choice /t 3 /n /d y >nul
netsh winsock reset
netsh winhttp reset proxy
netsh http flush log buffer
net start dot3svc
netsh lan reconnect
net stop dot3svc
choice /t 3 /n /d y >nul
netsh int ip reset
netsh int ipv4 reset
netsh int ipv6 reset
netsh int httpstunnel reset
netsh int portproxy reset
netsh int tcp reset
choice /t 3 /n /d y >nul
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /all
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /registerdns
ipconfig /renew
shutdown /r /t 0
```

And I can access Microsoft Store again...

Comment: Having to restart my computer everytime I want to use Store is tedious and frustrating, as I always use proxies, I don't know how to add Microsoft sites to proxy bypass list, yet...(I don't know where system proxy bypass list is)